# Java interface inheritance causes IDE confusion

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, interface, intellij-idea

I have interfaces extending other interfaces. When the implementations of those interfaces are used, my IDE (Eclipse and IntelliJ idea) is unable to resolve the implementing class. This does not prevent the code from compiling, but it's very peculiar that the IDE is so uncertain. Is there something fundamental I am misunderstanding? I present a simplified structure that outlines the problem.

A base interface

```
public interface Avoidable {

    public void avoid();

}
```

An interface that extends the base one

```
public interface MostlyAvoidable extends Avoidable {

    public void most();

}
```

It's implementation

```
public class MostlyAvoidableImpl implements MostlyAvoidable {
    @Override
    public void most() {}

    @Override
    public void avoid() {}
}
```

A second extending interface

```
public interface SomewhatAvoidable extends Avoidable {

    public void somewhat();

}
```

And its implementation

```
public class SomewhatAvoidableImpl implements SomewhatAvoidable {

    @Override
    public void avoid() {}

    @Override
    public void somewhat() {}

}
```

Finally a class that uses one of these implementations:

```
public class UsesSomewhatAvoidable {

    private SomewhatAvoidable somewhatAvoidable;

    public UsesSomewhatAvoidable(SomewhatAvoidable somewhatAvoidable) {
        this.somewhatAvoidable = somewhatAvoidable;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        somewhatAvoidable.avoid();
    }
}
```

Now, if I navigate to the somewhatAvoidable.avoid(); line and ask the IDE to find the code that implements the avoid() method, it asks me if I mean MostlyAvoidableImpl or SomewhatAvoidableImpl. Why? Surely it can figure this out?

This is what happens in Idea 10.5 when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (admittedly quite an old version now), but it also happens in the latest version of Eclipse.

[image: Idea 10.5 behaviour]

Edit: corrected typo in last line - SimplyAvoidImpl to SomewhatAvoidableImpl, and added screenshot.

Comment: Where is `SimplyAvoidImpl`?

Comment: @Code-Guru Don't you think it is just a typo?

Comment: @maba Most likely. But it is difficult to deduce what the correction should be.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and effort to show us a simplified example of your problem. You should be careful to create a new project and actually "run" your example to double-check that it recreates the same issue that you have in your actual code.

Comment: I assure you I created a real project to reproduce the problem, and have added a screenshot to demonstrate.

Comment: @ChrisWelsh Thanks for the screenshot for clarification. I think the answers given provide some good suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I took all your interfaces and classes and set it up in my own IntelliJ and I don't have the problem you describe.

Position the caret at the `avoid` method in `UsesSomewhatAvoidable` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (`Go To | Implementation(s)`):

[image]

And I end up at the implementation in `SomewhatAvoidableImpl`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble. I guess upgrading to Idea 12 would help (as it seems like it's fixed the problem I describe), but it's mostly affecting Eclipse developers.

Comment: @ChrisWelsh Yes it seems to be working. It might have been a bug or it might never have been implemented the way it works now. Going with the latest IDE versions is always preferable. I don't use Eclipse myself (for various reasons) so I can't speak for those using it. So you should definitely upgrade to IntelliJ version 12.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely it can figure this out?

Yes, it should be able to figure out that the `avoid()` method executes using the interface given by `SomewhatAvoidable`. If it's giving a completely different class (such as `MostlyAvoidableImpl` in this case) then as far as I can see that would be a bug (with the example you've given anyway, I can't see how `SomewhatAvoidable` could possibly relate to `MostlyAvoidableImpl`.) It's possible you've confused the IDE somehow - try cleaning or restarting and see if it makes a difference.

However, it may validly give you an option to select an implementation more specifically, since this cannot be determined by static analysis (but obviously one such implementation has to be selected for the program to work correctly at runtime.)

Comment: This is a wide problem that is affecting all our code and all our developers. I distilled the problem down to what I thought was a representative example.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have given, `somewhatAvoidable` (in the `UsesSomewhatAvoidable` class) is declared as a `SomewhatAvoidable` which is an interface and doesn't have an implementation for the `avoid()` method. The compiler (and thus the IDE) cannot know which class you want to jump to for the implementation.

Comment: But according to the OP, the IDE is suggesting `MostlyAvoidableImpl`, which cannot possibly be correct...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good point. The OP also claims that the IDE suggests a class which doesn't even exist in the example. I intentionally avoided those details in this answer because I'm unsure what is *actually* happening on the OP's end.

Comment: somewhatAvoidable is declared as SomewhatAvoidable, which is implemented by SomewhatAvoidableImpl, which has a method implementing avoid().